# Allow user to change selection in dropdown list a maximum of 6 times but have the code run after each change in selection

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to have a VBA code where the user is only allowed to change their selection in a dropdown box a maximum of 6 times? I need the macro assigned with the dropdown box to run after each time the user selects a value from the dropdown box.

I have tried the following:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
With Worksheets("Information Sheet").Shapes("Drop Down 14")
    If Worksheets("Disp_&_Result_Calc").Range("Z1") = "" Then
        Call CombinedMacro2
    Else
        MsgBox ("You have specified the maximum number of depths!")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: have a cell on a hidden sheet (allows persistence) or a static variable (resets on each load) that records the number of times changes are made. Exit code if limit is exceeded

Comment: The answer is probably Yes - what did you already try, and what issues did you run into?

Comment: Sure - you'll may want to look into `Worksheet Change()` event. What have you tried? Is it a maximum of changer per Excel session, or over the lifetime of a document?

Comment: Maximum per excel session. I have tried the following.. Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
With Worksheets("Information Sheet").Shapes("Drop Down 14")
If Worksheets("Disp_&_Result_Calc").Range("Z1") = "" Then
Call CombinedMacro2
Else
MsgBox ("You have specified the maximum number of depths!")
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think the STATIC Statement might be useful in this situation.  It will cause the variable defined to retain its value "as long as the code is running".  I understand this to mean that the procedure in which the STATIC variable is declared can modify the variable and exit.  When the same procedure is invoked again, the variable will have the same value (rather than being reinitialized as a variable defined by DIM would be).  Exiting and restarting the module would reinitialize the STATIC variable.